# Weblogic 10.3 logging implementation

Tags: logging, weblogic

I m trying to implement `org.apache.commons.logging.Log` implementation. I copied 2 lib `jars` into `domainhome/lib` folder acc to http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13739/config_logs.htm#i1014785.

If i use `System.setProperty(LogFactory.FACTORY_PROPERTY, "weblogic.logging.commons.LogFactoryImpl");`  before creating logger instance (by using `LogFactory.getFactory().getInstance(this.getClass());`) it works. But i do not want to use `setProperty` on every class by this way. So i manipulated my `setDomainEnv.cmd` (see below plz) as adding

`-Dweblogic.logging.commons.LogFactoryImpl=org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory`

argument, i have not faced any exception when i start weblogic by that way but it does not writeout any log.
Plz help me that what i missed?
Thx in advance
Brgds

```
setDomainEnv.cmd
...
set EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES=-Dweblogic.logging.commons.LogFactoryImpl=org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory %EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES%
...



MainManagerBean.class
@Stateless(name="MainManager", mappedName = "MainManager")
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@Interceptors(value = { PerformanceMonitor.class, ProfileInterceptor.class })
public class MainManagerBean implements MainManager, MainManagerLocal
{
    private Log logger =LogFactory.getFactory().getInstance(this.getClass());


    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "EJBModel")
    private EntityManager manager;


    @Resource
    SessionContext ctx;


    @PostConstruct
    public void initialized()
    {
        //System.setProperty(LogFactory.FACTORY_PROPERTY, "weblogic.logging.commons.LogFactoryImpl");
        //  logger= LogFactory.getFactory().getInstance(this.getClass());
        logger.debug("MainManagerBean is initialized");
        logger.info("MainManagerBean is initialized");
        logger.trace("MainManagerBean is initialized");
....}}
```

Comment: http://buttso.blogspot.de/2011/06/using-slf4j-with-weblogic-server.html

Answer (score 1):

You have the log factory property reversed. You show it as:

```
-Dweblogic.logging.commons.LogFactoryImpl=org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
```

When it should be:

```
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory=weblogic.logging.commons.LogFactoryImpl
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11036_01/wlevs20/config_server/logging.html

Comment: Changed acc.to this info, that works. Thankyou so much. But that causes a new problem that i could not understand. With this conf, when trying to reach wl admin console through browser, throws <Servlet: "ResourceServlet" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "console".
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError.The chosen LogFactory implementation does not extend LogFactory. Please check your configuration. (Caused by java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.logging.commons.LogFactoryImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory)

Comment: Not sure why that would happen but maybe you can try `-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl` instead or see if one of the answers here helps https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1078003